# Script in sidebar blocks other widget's load

Tags: widgets, sidebar

in my Sidebar, before the widget generated from Wordpress, I have this PHP script that fetches the latest threads from my vBulletin 4 Forum:

```
                    <div class="box newtopics">
                    <h1><span style="color: #505050;">Nuove discussioni</span></h1>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <ul>
                            <?php

/* Get vBulletins latest topics */
// Getting DB Connection variables
include('./wp-content/themes/V6/includes/database.php');
$connvb = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $connvb ) {
  die('Non riesco a connettermi al database: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM thread WHERE forumid NOT IN (37,38,39) ORDER by dateline DESC LIMIT 5';
$count = 0;

mysql_select_db($dbname);
mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8`");

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connvb );

while($count < 5 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $count++;
?>

<li>
  <span class="useravatar" style="background-image: url('/forum/image.php?u=<?php echo $row['postuserid']; ?>');"></span>
  <span class="topic">
     <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/forum/showthread.php?<?php echo $row['threadid']; ?>"><p id="title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></p></a>
     <p id="info">Postato da <?php echo $row['postusername']; ?>, <?php
$time = date('d/m/Y', $row['dateline']);
echo $time;
?></p>
  </span>
</li>
<?php
}
mysql_close($connvb);
?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But, all the widget that are loaded after from Wordpress doesn't work.

This is the code after this script:

```
                <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
    || !dynamic_sidebar(1) ) : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT
With the debug, the Tag cloud (widget after the vB script) gives me this error:

```
Errore sul database di WordPress: [Table 'forumdb.wp_terms' doesn't exist]
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY tt.count DESC LIMIT 45
Errore sul database di WordPress: [Table 'forumdb.wp_posts' doesn't exist]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpdmpro' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question. You will very likely get a lot of errors for using functions that are outdated for a very long time.

Comment: Just added the error i get with the debug, in one of the widgets after my script.